# Как загрузить на FTP папку с файлами?

Tags: ftp, upload

Не подскажите, как это сделать? Я погулил, но что-то ничего внятного не нашел.

Везде даны примеры с файлами, а мне папка с подкаталогами нужна.

Comment: А обязательно таким стандартным средством пользоваться? Ведь есть куча простых в использовании программ, типа FileZilla?

Comment: Нужно что-то консольное и портабельное, что можно с собой носить и чему можно аргументы передавать.

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос решался на **CyberForum**, [прочитайте](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread915375.html), пожалуйста. Хотя, вот сразу можно:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

::========= Настройки для отправляемых файлов ========
::Исходная папка с отправляемыми файлами (на сервере будет создана автоматически)
set SourceDir=h:\1\Tempo
::Маска для отправляемых файлов
set mask=*.*

::Временный файл команд для утилиты FTP.exe
set CommFTP=%temp%\FTP_out.tmp

::========= Настройки для подключения к серверу FTP =========
::Адрес сервера - имя, либо IP-адрес
set host=31.170.164.xx
::Номер порта (по-умолчанию: 21)
set port=21
::Имя пользователя
set user=u471327xxx
::Пароль
set password=xxxxxxxx
::Системная папка FTP (если на Вашем сервере такая отсутствует, не указывать)
set Mainfolder=public_html
::Подкаталог на FTP
set SubFolder=Test

::Добавляем утилиту FTP в исключения брандмауера Windows
netsh firewall add allowedprogram "%windir%\system32\ftp.exe" ENABLE >nul

::Убираем лишний концевой слэш, если такой указан
if "%SourceDir:~-1%"=="\" Set "SourceDir=%SourceDir:~0,-1%"

::Отделить только имя папки
For /D %%a In ("%SourceDir%") Do Set onlyDir=%%~na

Call :CheckConnection
Call :FTP_Init_String
ftp.exe -s:"%CommFTP%"

pause
endlocal
exit /B

:FTP_Init_String
::Начальная конфигурация подключения к FTP
> "%CommFTP%" (
  echo open %host% %port%
  echo %user%
  echo.%password%
  echo binary
  echo prompt
  echo hash
  echo lcd "%SourceDir%"
  if "%Mainfolder%" neq "" echo cd "%Mainfolder%"
  if "%SubFolder%" neq "" echo cd "%SubFolder%"
  echo mkdir "%onlyDir%"
  echo cd "%onlyDir%"
  echo mput %mask%
  echo disconnect
  echo bye
)
exit /b

:CheckConnection
  ping -n 1 8.8.8.8 |>nul find /i "TTL=" || (echo Нет подключения к сети Интернет&           Goto :CheckConnection)
exit /b
```

Comment: Спасибо, а есть ли какие-то более простые утилиты, пусть и сторонние, но консольные. Нужна только возможность загрузить папки и файлы и все.

Comment: Ну, в плане мобильности. Вам нужна работа на разных машинах?